# Filter variable by number of records in a dataframe with multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2461 observations and 80 variables retrieved from BOLD.

```
Scleractinia <- read_tsv("http://www.boldsystems.org/index.php/API_Public/combined?taxon=Scleractinia&format=tsv")
```

Currently I am in the filtering process of this dataframe. Currently I have filtered the dataframe by "markercode" and "nucleotides". I want to filter the dataframe further by only keeping "species_name" that have more than 5 records.

```
Scleractinia.COI5P <- Scleractinia %>%
  filter(markercode == "COI-5P") %>%
  filter(str_detect(nucleotides, "[ACGT]"))
#This is a subset of the main dataset that includes only records with the marker code "COI-5P" and nucleotide sequences.

unique(Scleractinia.COI5P$species_name)
#There are 479 unique species present in this dataset. This is too many to work with so we are going to filter out species that don't have more than 5 records. 

SpeciesCount <- table(Scleractinia.COI5P$species_name)
#This creates a table of species and the number of records available in the dataset for this species.
```

I created "SpeciesCount" to determine the 5 record threshold since there were a lot of species with just 1 record. I don't know how to go about filtered Scleractinia.COI5P such that the 80 variables(that are columns) are still available.

I tried:

```
test <- Scleractinia.COI5P %>%
  filter(table(Scleractinia.COI5P$species_name) > 5)
```

But this resulted in 0 observations with 80 variables. Essentially I want the 80 variables to remain so I can explore further what needs to be filtered out but I want species only with greater than or equal to 5 records in Scleractinia.COI5P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr, you just need to slightly change your pipe operation. Group by species name and then filter

```
library(tidyverse)

##Filter first
Scleractinia.COI5P <- Scleractinia %>%
  filter(markercode == "COI-5P") %>%
  filter(str_detect(nucleotides, "[ACGT]"))


##Group by and then filter
filtered_data_frame <- Scleractinia.COI5P %>% 
                       group_by(species_name) %>% filter(n() >=5)

##check to see if only species with over 5 records are represented
total_species <- count(filtered_data_frame, sort = TRUE)
```